# iCal events missing problem

Tags: macos, ical, calendar

I have recently updated my Mac OS X to 10.8 version. The iCal application is changed as "Calendar" app in OS X 10.8. The problem here is, I lost all data which I stored in iCal. Any suggestions to retrieve those data's?

Thanks

Comment: Did you have your calendar in iCloud or Gmail? Or just stored localy?

Comment: I just stored locally :(

Comment: Do you have a backup...Time Machine, for example?

Comment: No, I did not use Time Machine and all. I stored events only in iCal. Also, I lost all my stickies :(